# Need some help getting an html parsing project off the ground

Tags: html, parsing, html-parsing, extract

I came here for help, because I'm starting a project and I don't even know what questions to ask.

What it boils down to is that I have a bunch of html files that I need to parse for various pieces of information.  The files are archived from an online forum.  What I basically want to do is to be able to feed the program an html file and have it write the following information into a database:

-number of posts made by each user,timestamp of each post, whether or not a particular string appears in the message body

as well as some other similar bits of information.

Would HTML Parser be the direction to go?  I looked at it, but I honestly don't understand a lot about how to implement it.  I have a BS in computer science, but the programming portion of it mainly just focused on algorithms and solving basic logic problems.  We never learned anything about putting together large projects that contain multiple files, so my knowledge of how .jar files and different libraries are implemented is basically non-existent.

Anything to point me in the right direction would be very appreciated!

Comment: You didn't mention the language you're preferring, but since you were talking about jar files, I assume it's Java. I recommend using eclipse for Java projects. There are tons of good tutorials (google!) on how to get started with eclipse and working with libraries. Since you don't seem to know much about practical programming, you will have to start from scratch: Learn how to progam! Not before you grasp the basic concepts of a programming language, you will be able to tackle such a project.

Answer (score 0):

HTML parsing can be done in many languages.

If you have little or no programming experience, I recommend you start with Python. You will be able to get into it fairly quickly compared to Java. 
Take a look at Codecademy's Python track - http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python

There are many frameworks you can use to scrape an html in Python such as lxml, beautifulsoup and Scrapy. 
The choice you make between them depends on the extent of your problem, for example, how fast do you need your program to run? Can you scrape the html files with simple xpath expressions or will you need to implement your own functions for scraping?

For a quick and dirty solution I recommend BeautifulSoup. You won't even have to learn xpath to get the ball rolling. However, the framework is fairly slow from my experience so that might not be a good choice for a long term solution.

Good luck!